# String.fromCodePoint() does not return flag emoji

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to get emoji from Unicode, all Unicode is returning emoji but only country flag emoji is not returning emoji, it returns the first alphabet of the emoji name.

Here is my code:

`String.fromCodePoint(parseInt('1f1fa-1f1f8', 16)) //`  this code is returning  instead of

but if i use other emoji code instead of flag emoji code it is working.  `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt('1f61b', 16)) //` this code is returning the correct emoji

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `1f1fa-1f1f8` looks like two characters - which `parseInt` doesn't know of course. `String.fromCodePoint(0x1f1fa, 0x1f1f8)` should do, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt('1f1fa-1f1f8', 16)` is returning `127482` which is same as `parseInt('1f1fa', 16)`

So to solve this, you can split them by the hyphen (-)

```
var c = '1f1fa-1f1f8'.split('-')
                     .map(i => parseInt(i,16))
String.fromCodePoint(...c) // us
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt('1f1fa', 16), parseInt('1f1f8', 16))`

`parseInt` was only returning the first byte, instead of both. As far as I know, `parseInt` can only parse a single value at a time.